# SelectedIndex always 0 Postback Enabled, checking !Postback doesn't appear to do trick

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm having a struggle with a DropDownList's `SelectedIndex`. It always appears to be returning as `0`. I am filling a dropdown list based on results of a linq query. 
After selecting an option from the drop down list and hitting `Button1, Button1` *returns* the `SelectedIndex` which is always `0`.
I have attempted adding `if (!Page.IsPostback)` within the Page Load area, this changes the `SelectedIndex` to `-1` .. Relevant Code Below

```
<script runat="server">
    int dropDownCounter = 0;
    public string levelselected = null;

    void Level_Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        roledropdown.Controls.Clear();
        CheckBox chkList1;
        chkList1 = new CheckBox();
        chkList1.Text = (LevelOptions.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        chkList1.CssClass = "roleCheckBox";
        chkList1.ID = "xxxx";
        roledropdown.Controls.Add(chkList1);
        roledropdown.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
        UpdatePanel.Update();
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AsyncScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(LevelOptions);
        AsyncScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Button1);

        var levels = new List <SelectListItem>();

        foreach(var x in userRoleQuery)
        {
        //Add the levels to a dropdown menue
        ListItem gg = new ListItem();
        gg.Text = "Hello";
        gg.Value = (dropDownCounter.ToString());
        if (dropDownCounter == 0) 
        {
            gg.Selected = true;
            levelselected = (x.LevelId.ToString());
        }
        LevelOptions.Items.Add(gg);
    }
    dropDownCounter++;
}
</script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="LevelOptions" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Level_Index_Changed">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="roledropdown" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update Both Panels" OnClick="Level_Index_Changed" />
```

Comment: Why does `Button1` call the same function as selecting an item from the dropdown? That seems odd.

Comment: I was having some difficulties getting the event to fire in the first place so I added a button instead to test it after changing

Comment: When you call the same function from the button the selected index of a button is 0, not really since buttons don't have a selected index, but it will be effectively the same thing.  What are your results when you change the selection in the dropdown?